# Implement multi-factor authentication using Spring Oauth2 with custom grant type

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to implement multi-factor authentication (mfa) with spring oauth2. I have my own authorization server and I'm trying to follow this guide https://sultanov.dev/blog/multi-factor-authentication-with-spring-boot-and-oauth2. I made two custom granter **CustomePasswordTokenGranter** and **MFATokenGranter**. **CustomePasswordTokenGranter** will return access_token with authority pre_auth to be used with **MFATokenGranter** later.

```
CustomPasswordTokenGranter -> username, password -> Oauth2AccessToken(authorities = [PRE_AUTH])
MFATokenGranter -> access_token -> do I need to check wheter it contains PRE_AUTH or not?


public class MfaTokenGranter extends AbstractTokenGranter {
    @Override
    protected OAuth2Authentication getOAuth2Authentication(ClientDetails client, TokenRequest tokenRequest) {
        // do I need this line of code?
        if(!client.getAuthorities().contains(PRE_AUTH)) {
           throw new InvalidAuthorityException();
        }
    }
}
```

btw I'm not sure if I have to check authority of a client that trying to access this granter. I want the token that was generated from **CustomePasswordTokenGranter** to be used with **MfaTokenGranter** only. Does spring automatically check that for me or I have to do it my own or it doesn't matter if I check it or not?

Comment: This might seem pure trolling, but I really wonder why so many people want to reinvent the weel. Why exactly do you want to implement, test and maintain such security-sensitive features that are already provided by many OIDC providers (Keycloak, Auth0, Okta, Amazon Cognito, etc.)?

Comment: @ch4mp multi-factor authentication with oauth2 wasn't provided by spring

Comment: No, but it is by all the OIDC authorization-servers I listed

Comment: In addition to user registration, user management screens (including roles assignment), social login, connection to LDAP, etc.

Comment: The new Spring Authorization Server, not offer the posibility to create a custom grant type, but you can do it by creating your own flow and overriding the main authorization flow. I´ve been preparing an example to show how can we do it.